# I need a word to that means something similar to "marvel" or "savor"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, connotation

For reference, here is the sentence: The world was beautiful and I was too busy running to _____ it.
For context, the character is on the run and notices the beauty but doesn't get to ____.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/savor

Comment: Perhaps *appreciate.*

Comment: @Xanne Maybe also "admire" or "cherish."